# Maven docbkx plugin and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, docbook

I would like to use the Maven plugin docbkx to generate PDF and HTML output from DocBook using Maven running within Eclipse. As described [here](http://docbkx-tools.sourceforge.net/advanced.html) I try to use customization. Unfortunately Eclipse complains about a missing include:

> Missing include: urn:docbkx:stylesheet

The missing include seems to be a symbolic reference to the original stylesheet that is resolved by the plugin. How can I fix the Eclipse error?